# How to do Blade Element Momentum Theory Analysis for NACA airfoils?

Tags: aerodynamics, turbines, propulsion, wind-tunnels

I wanna perform BEMT analysis on blades of different geometry and not just symmetric thin airfoil. How to do this?

Comment: Use a CFD package? Star CD, Phoenics - there are many, but if you  can't afford those then OpenFoam etc

Comment: This question is better directed to the Aviation SE site where aerodynamics experts reside.

Comment: Have you looked at [QProp](http://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/qprop/qprop_doc.txt) from MIT?

Comment: This is also a very useful document as it derives (finally, after a 100 years of trying) a closed form solution to the major design variables of the optimum propeller. https://openscholarship.wustl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=2174&context=etd

Answer (score 0):

One book I've used in the past is Martin O. L. Hansen's **'Aerodynamics of wind turbines'**.

It covers extensively and step by step the beam element momentum theory. I've used it in the past to develop software for a wind energy project. The project used NACA airfoils, so you should be able to apply it to your work.

Last I remember I could find chapters or the whole thing available in public websites, so a quite search might yield some results.